# Using linq to combine objects

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have 2 instances of a class that implements the `IEnumerable` interface. I would like to create a new object and combine both of them into one. I understand I can use the `for..each` to do this.

Is there a linq/lambda expression way of doing this?

EDIT

```
public class Messages : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<Message>
{
  private List<Message> message = new List<Message>();

  //Other methods
}
```

Code to combine

```
MessagesCombined messagesCombined = new MessagesCombined();

MessagesFirst messagesFirst = GetMessageFirst();
MessagesSecond messagesSecond = GetMessageSecond();

messagesCombined = (Messages)messagesFirst.Concat(messagesSecond); //Throws runtime exception
```

//Exception is

```
Unable to cast object of type '<ConcatIterator>d__71`1[Blah.Message]' to type 'Blah.Messages'.
```

Comment: IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T>?  And do you mean a set join, union, or intersect?

Comment: I looked again and surprisingly, it implements BOTH IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>. Didn't know we could do that. I mean set union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var combined = firstSequence.Concat(secondSequence);
```

This is using the [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) extension method.

Comment: Why are you creating custom classes for set of messages?  Just use `IEnumerable<Message>` for all 3.  The problem you are having is that you are trying to assign `Messages` to an instance of something more derived, which is not allowed.

Comment: >> Why are you creating custom classes for set of messages?

I am working with existing types. I am not the author of Messages and Message class.

Comment: @DotnetDude, so how did you beat the problem? Why did you chose the answer — aren't that didn't worked?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with an array of byte. What I did to solve my issue:

```
col1.Concat(col2).ToArray();
```

If you got a list:

```
col1.Concat(col2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx).

```
Pet[] cats = GetCats();
Pet[] dogs = GetDogs();

IEnumerable<Pet> query = cats.Concat(dogs);
```

Per your edit:

```
IEnumerable<Message> messagesCombined;

MessagesFirst messagesFirst = GetMessageFirst();
MessagesSecond messagesSecond = GetMessageSecond();

// if this doesn't work, you can cast both MessagesFirst and MessagesSecond to IEnumerable<Message>
messagesCombined = messagesFirst.Concat(messagesSecond);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Enumarable.Concat` method returns an `IEnumerable<Message>` (or in fact an `<ConcatIterator>d__71<Message>` as the exception message shows). You can not cast that to your `Messages` type. You can do the following:

```
var m = new Messages(messagesFirst.Concat(messagesSecond));
```

And make sure your `Messages` type has a constructor taking an `IEnumerable<Message>`:

```
public class Messages : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<Message>
{
    private List<Message> message;

    public Message(IEnumerable<Message> messages)
    {
        this.message = new List<Message>(messages);
    }

    //Other methods
}
```

Comment: @Steven - I need the result to be of type Messages. var wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Well, it is of type Messages. "var" just instructs the compiler to "guess" the most correct type according to what's on the right side of the statement; in this case, the creation of a Messages object.

It's called "type inference", and it's really useful.

Comment: @Smith - So, if the combining logic is in a method with return param of Messages, can I return a object of type "var" without the compiler complaining or any exceptions at runtime? Also, I do further processing of the combined list, so at some point i have to cast it to Messages.

Comment: From MSDN: "Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type." If I write"var i = 2;", then i will be of type int, because 2 is of type int. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: @Smith - Thanks for the explanation. I do understand that the type of var is the type that is inferred from the right side of the equation. However, the issue i have is that I cannot return an object of type var from the method with return type of Members.

Comment: @DotnetDude: There is no such thing as a `var` object type. As Smith tries to explain, the C# compiler just fils in the correct type for you. If your method returns `Messages`, then you can return `m`, because `m` will be of type `Messages` (in my example that is).

Comment: It is a half of an answer — types gone wrong. Okay. But where's the second part — how would one extract the «Messages» from the IEnumerable? I.e. I need to return an exact type, and it is not this «enumerable».

Comment: Aha, I found it! The gist is that this IEnumerable have a function that looks like `ToSomething` *(i.e. `ToArray`, `ToList`)*. You may add it to the answer ☺